# Print the contents of an array to the console using ARM assembly

Tags: linux, arm, assembly

I am trying to write a code in Assembly (ARM arch) that prints the contents of an array to the console. I have written the following code:

```
.data

.balign 4
a: .skip 12     //define an array of (4bytes * 3)

.text
.global main

main:
mov r0, #1     //for stdout
ldr r1, addr_a     //load the address of the array
mov r2, #4         //the length of an integer 4 bytes

mov r3, sp        //puts into r3 the address that points the SP
str r3, [r1]      //store the address into the first position of the array
str r3, [r1, #+4]  //same at the second position 

mov r7, #4       //make the sys_call write
swi 0            //software interrupt

mov r7, #1
swi 0

addr_a: .word a
```

When I compile the code I do not receive any error. However this prints on the console some raw data like nonsense characters. 
Anyone can help me to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The `write` syscall does not write numbers, it writes text. You need to convert your numbers to text yourself. Plenty of examples for that, do some research.

Comment: Thanks @Jester I will make my research on that. Do you think that If I do this conversion it will works?